# Sitefinity Require SSL

Tags: ssl, sitefinity

I have made changes to sitefinity with require SSL is true so that I get canonical tag with https which will avoid duplicate link issue for seo. it works fine on the servers.

The problem is we are using load balancer to do ssl offloading. So when we access from browser outside the servers I get redirect loops.I can understand the issue as Load Balancers call the website with http port 80 and then site redirects everything to https.

In this scenerio what will be your solutions to enable the canonical tag to work with https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set EnableSslOffloading to true in 
Administration » Settings » Advanced » System » SSL Offloading ?

More details here: 
http://docs.sitefinity.com/administration-ssl-offloading

Comment: Yes. I have enabled SSL offloading. Since the request from load balancer is http sitefinity process the site with http which results canonical tag in http. even though the site is https.  When I access the site on webserver with https I can see canonical tag with https.Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Did you also have the HttpHeaderFieldName and HttpHeaderFieldValue?

Comment: One important thing in the SSL offloading process is to send the HTTP header, which you configured in your advanced settings, with every HTTP request. The default HTTP header used for this purpose is `X-Forwarded-Proto`. Its default value is `https`.
In other words, the load balancer should add this header to every HTTP (not secured) request it sends to Sitefinity.